# Массив с размерностью на 1 больше вводимого

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Нужно создать массив, количество строк и стоблцов которого будет на 1 больше вводимого массива.

```
import numpy as np
y = int(input('Количество элементов строки: '))
x = int(input('Количество строк: '))
matrix = np.array([[y for y in input('Значения матрицы построчно: ').split()] for x in range(x)], dtype=int)
    if x < 4 and y< 4:
        matrix = np.append(matrix, 1, axis=0)
        matrix = np.append(matrix, 1, axis=1)
```

Пыталась подогнать под вводимую матрицу 3х3, выводит ошибку:

> all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 2 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
matrix = np.ndarray(shape=(x+1,y+1))
```

И потом заполняйте как хотите.

Добавить к уже существующей матрице с известными размерами `х` и `у`:

```
z_x = np.zeros((x, 1))
matrix = np.append(matrix, z_x, axis=1)
z_y = np.zeros((1, y+1))
matrix = np.append(matrix, z_y, axis=0)
print(matrix)
```

Comment: дело в том, что массив надо сначала заполнить, а потом уже строку и столбец добавить

Comment: Если вы сразу запрашиваете х и у, то какая разница?

Comment: это часть кода для решения матричной игры, там по условию находятся верхняя и нижняя границы, при условии, что они равны, матрица не меняется, в другом случае нужно добавить строку и столбец

Comment: @strquest дополнил

Answer (score 2):

Пример добавления столбца и строки к *существующей* матрице:

```
In [63]: a = np.arange(1, 13).reshape(4, 3)

In [64]: a
Out[64]:
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6],
       [ 7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12]])

In [65]: a = np.hstack((a, np.zeros((a.shape[0], 1))))

In [66]: a
Out[66]:
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.,  0.],
       [10., 11., 12.,  0.]])

In [67]: a = np.vstack((a, np.zeros((1, a.shape[1]))))

In [68]: a
Out[68]:
array([[ 1.,  2.,  3.,  0.],
       [ 4.,  5.,  6.,  0.],
       [ 7.,  8.,  9.,  0.],
       [10., 11., 12.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]])
```